# how to check the value of submitted form field against an variable array

Tags: jquery

I have a simple post code check, I'd to check the submitted value against a pre-made variable, how can I do this in Jquery,

```
  <form method="post" action="#">
     <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" size="8" maxlength="8" />
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

and my variable contains B1,B2 and B3.

if the post code entered is similar to the variable an ok message is sent otherwise a no message is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to check if submitted postcode is partially matches a list of district postcodes (like B1, B2, B3 which are Birmingham districts)

```
var districtPostcodes = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4'];
$("#submit_postcode").click(function(){
    var userPostcode = $("#postcode").val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gi,'').toUpperCase();
    $.grep(districtPostcodes , function(val, i){
        if(userPostcode.indexOf(val) === 0){
            alert("Users postcode is part of district: "+val)
        }
    })
})
```

The function only matches postcodes that begin with the predefined districts (this only succeeding is the entered postcode is **inside** this district)

I have also used some ids for your elements as it makes sense and improves code clarity 
You can check the [demo here](http://jsbin.com/eyasi/) (use B24EZ as postcode)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   var textfield = $('#textfield').val();
   if ( textfield == B1 || textfield == B2 || textfield == B3){
       alert('ok'); 
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
});
```

something like this?
you should give your form an ID . In fact the documentation has a good example: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit
**EDIT:** Whoops, didn't get the part with the part of... see bottom example with grep

Answer (score 0):

```
var varArray = [B1,B2,B3];

$('form submit').click(function(){
   var textfield = $('#textfield').val();
   if ( varArray.indexOf(textField) > -1){
      alert('ok'); return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
});
```

That will give you what you want. You can add things to your array as you see fit that way was well.

Comment: i think that click doesn't stop submitting with return key